# How can I send push notification with fcm through jabber server

Tags: push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, ejabberd, smack

I have developed a chat application for android using **ejabberd** as **XMPP server**. I want to send **FCM push notification**, when user is offline.

Can anyone help me or give an example for this ?

Comment: Push notifications when user is offline? :O Do you mean actually attempting to send a notification, even if the device is not online?

Comment: Yes i want to send push notification when the user is **offline** or my app in **background**.

Comment: I'm confuse, how can i _**connect**_ my **ejabberd (XMPP server)** with **FCM server**. please help me to solve this problem as soon as possible.

Comment: @ZainUlHassan you got any solution ?? if yes than please tell me i'm also stuck in this problem

Comment: I'm trying to solve it by given solution of #Maryna Krasnova . when i solved it then i'll inform you @VishalPatoliyaツ

Comment: how we can we implement this in android if you know than help me  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627599/how-to-configure-push-mode-configuration-in-xmpp-with-fcm-refresh-token-using-sm @ZainUlHassan

Answer (score 3):

You can add [apllication to connect to FCM](https://github.com/softwarejoint/fcm-erlang) to your ejabberd, and send notification each time message goes to offline storage with this library

Comment: thanks @Maryna Krasnova I'm trying to solve it with your given link!!!!!!!

Comment: @maryna how we can we implement this in android if you know than help me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41627599/how-to-configure-push-mode-configuration-in-xmpp-with-fcm-refresh-token-using-sm

Answer (score 2):

I got your mail, I am answering here so it can help others. You should look into this erlang library that I wrote.

https://github.com/softwarejoint/fcm-erlang

The read me section has all the details.

So, your app registers its push token on server. Then when there is a particular event on server, server uses that token to send fcm a message. fcm in-turn sends the message to you.

Best
Pankaj

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same task and finally solved it by writing my own Ejabberd module. I've stumbled over many problems since a lot has changed in later / the latest version(s) of Ejabberd.

[Here's my Stackoverflow question where I just added my now working code for the module.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41852133/ejabberd-error-in-simple-module-to-handle-offline-messages)

Maybe that help.