# How to implement FCM push notification in ejabberd XMPP server

Tags: android, erlang, xmpp, push, ejabberd

I have implemented apns notification using ejabberd, for apns we need to use mod_apns.erl file only.
I want to implement push notification in android device using FCM as GCM is deprecated. previously mod_gcm.erl file available for GCM push notification.

Please help me to integrate **FCM push notification in ejabberd**.

**Installed Ejabberd Version: 16.09**

Comment: have you found any solutions for this?

Comment: @VinayPandya
no, I have no found any solution. yet

Comment: i found one module which might help us https://github.com/proger/mod_pushoff

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try. Thanks again.